# get word before and after

Tags: arrays

I need to get the words before and after `"globe"` in the string text `"hello,planet,globe,city,country"`.

1. So, I was trying to get the word before `" ,globe,"` until the previous comma, meaning it should return `"planet"`.
   I also need to return the next word `"city"`.
2. If the word is at the beginning of the string, 
   previous word should be entered as `"no word"`.
   If the word is at the end of the string,
   next word should be entered as `"no word"`.

How do i do it? Thanks in advance. Is this `preg_match` the best choice?

```
$word = "fsdfs";
$text = "hello,planet,globe,city,country";
preg_match('/[$word]+/', $text, $match);
//the above sentence is wrong but wanted to emphasise that $word needs to  mentioned in it 
print_r($match);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^(.*?),?\s*globe\K(.*)$
```

You can use this and grab the capture or group.[See demo.](https://regex101.com/r/vP2zF2/1)

```
$re = "/^(.*?),?\\s*globe\\K(.*)$/m"; 
$str = "hello,planet,globe,city,country\nglobe,city,country\nhello,planet,globe"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match` is probably the wrong choice for this.

You have a few choices, you could use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to simply remove 'globe' from the string, then what you have left is what you want.

You could also use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to turn the string into an array and loop through it, when it matches 'globe' just skip it, you can use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to turn it back into a string.

Sample code:

```
$text = "hello,planet,globe,city,country";

$text = explode(',' , $text);

$key = array_search ('globe', $text);//just globe, no comma

echo $key;//key is 2 so

if($key == 0) {
    //first word so
    //first word is 'no word
} else {
    echo $text[1]; //word before
}

//should also check array keys are set before using them
echo $text[3];//word after
```

Updated:

```
$string = "hello,planet globe, city,country";

$regex = '/(?:[\w-]+ ){0,1}globe,(?: [\w-]+){0,1}/is';

preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks Coz for the answer but i forgot to mention that I should not use explode as the string text is going to be a big one later, So, can you please try the function with preg_match or preg_split?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `preg_match`. You can just split the text and search for the index of the word and after some checks return the left and right words.

```
function get_left_right_word($text, $word)
{
    $words = explode(',', $text);
    $i = array_search($word, $words);
    return array(
        $i === false || $i == 0 ? 'no word' : $words[i-1],
        $i === false || $i == count($words)-1 ? 'no word' : $words[i+1]
    );
}

list($left_word, $right_word) = get_left_right_word('hello,planet,globe,city,country', 'globe');
echo 'left: '.$left_word.' right: '.$right_word;
```

This will print

```
left: planet right: city
```

If you really want to use `preg_match` you can use is as

```
function get_left_right_word($text, $word)
{
    if (preg_match('/(?:(?<left>\w+),)?'.preg_quote($word, '/').'(?:,(?<right>\w+))?/', $text, $m))
    {
        return array(
            isset($m['left']) && $m['left'] ? $m['left'] : 'no word',
            isset($m['right']) && $m['right'] ? $m['right'] : 'no word'
        );
    }
    return array(
        'no word',
        'no word'
    );
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks... but do u know how to write regular expression for preg_match for this?

Comment: @goldy I added a `preg_match` example

Comment: **Always supply the 2nd parameter of `preg_quote()`**, otherwise, if the delimiter appears in the word, it may not be escaped.